# Printing string version of SSL structure for debugging

Tags: ssl, openssl, boringssl

For the purpose of debugging I am looking for a way to print the few important contents of the SSL structure in a human friendly way. Does a function already exist in the openssl libraries to do that?

The SSL handshake is failing in my custom private key method provider in  some cases and I was looking for ways to print the SSL parameters exchanged on the connection so far.

For eg., TLS version, cipher chosen, etc

Comment: The problem is probably around defining "important contents" as this may vary from someone to someone else. You may start by looking at openssl code for the x509 command that displays a certificate, and extract what you need there. `openssl x509 -text` basically calls this: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/e7fb44e7c3f7a37ff83a6b69ba51a738e549bf5c/crypto/x509/t_x509.c#L47